# Import database MySQL fastest way

Tags: mysql, database, import, mariadb

I'm looking for the fastest way to import database. The problem is that I use mysqldump export database. My database is over 2 GB on disk.

`mysqldump` is quite fast, but the import takes a long time. Is there a quick way to import a database?

We tried to implement hot backup, but MySQL not loaded. Are there options how to do a quick export-import? That is a simple copy of the database files in the data folder?

Info server:
OS: MS Windows Server 2008
MySQL Server: MySQL 5.5 or MariaDB
Tables Type: InnoDB (if MariaDB - InnoDB plugin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to copy the InnoDB files to from one server to another. If you have "innodb file per table" enabled, it'll be a lot easier. Following the instructions in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-copying.html) you can do:

> 1. On the source server, create a table if one does not already exist:
>
>    mysql> use test;
>      mysql> CREATE TABLE t(c1 INT) engine=InnoDB;
> 2. On the destination server, create a table if one does not exist:
>
>    mysql> use test; 
>      mysql> CREATE TABLE t(c1 INT) engine=InnoDB;
> 3. On the destination server, discard the existing tablespace. (Before a
>      tablespace can be imported, InnoDB must discard the tablespace that is
>      attached to the receiving table.)
>
>    mysql> ALTER TABLE t DISCARD TABLESPACE;
> 4. On the source server, run FLUSH TABLES ... FOR EXPORT to quiesce the
>      table and create the .cfg metadata file:
>
>    mysql> use test; 
>      mysql> FLUSH TABLES t FOR EXPORT;
>
>    The metadata (.cfg) file is created in the InnoDB data directory. Note
>
>    > FLUSH TABLES ... FOR EXPORT is available as of MySQL 5.6.6. The
>    >     statement ensures that changes to the named tables have been flushed
>    >     to disk so that binary table copies can be made while the server is
>    >     running. When FLUSH TABLES ... FOR EXPORT is run, InnoDB produces a
>    >     .cfg file in the same database directory as the table. The .cfg file
>    >     contains metadata used for schema verification when importing the
>    >     tablespace file.
> 5. Copy the .ibd file and .cfg metadata file from the source server to
>      the destination server. For example:
>
>    shell> scp /path/to/datadir/test/t.{ibd,cfg}
>      destination-server:/path/to/datadir/test
>
>    > Note
>    >
>    > The .ibd file and .cfg file must be copied before releasing the shared
>    >     locks, as described in the next step.
> 6. On the source server, use UNLOCK TABLES to release the locks acquired
>      by FLUSH TABLES ... FOR EXPORT:
>
>    mysql> use test; 
>      mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
> 7. On the destination server, import the tablespace:
>
>    mysql> use test; 
>      mysql> ALTER TABLE t IMPORT TABLESPACE;
>
>    > Note
>    >
>    > The ALTER TABLE ... IMPORT TABLESPACE feature does not enforce foreign
>    >     key constraints on imported data. If there are foreign key constraints
>    >     between tables, all tables should be exported at the same (logical)
>    >     point in time. In this case you would stop updating the tables, commit
>    >     all transactions, acquire shared locks on the tables, and then perform
>    >     the export operation.

Comment: But there is a solution for the entire database at once? not to block all tables by one?

Comment: `FLUSH TABLES tbl_name [, tbl_name] ... FOR EXPORT;` supports multiple tables at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I hope i think helpful for you... try to IMPORT CSV file easy way to load database.

For example:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path/caption.csv'
INTO TABLE caption
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(id, name)
```

Or you can use this software:

HeidiSQL SQL Editors software

Comment: this way to be able to move all indexes, stored procedures, triggers?

Comment: database consists of 700 tables, this method allows to dump the entire database at once, so as not to export each table for one?

Comment: This only works for text files, such as CSV and TSV files, and therefore isn't an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue with MySQL while importing data, after tuning below parameters :

1. max_allowed_packet = 1024M
2. innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G

import time reduced significantly.

Answer (score 0):

## The fastest way

I've used the solution below to import 100GB database (not a typo) of almost 300M records in less than 10 hours, so it's safe to say it will rip through the average SQL dump in no time.

First, you should make sure your database is making the most of your hardware - most out-of-the-box SQL installations are set up to be as lightweight (and therefore inefficient) as possible. Assuming you're using InnoDB (which you will be if using XAMPP), edit the following variables in your `my.ini` file (located at *C:\XAMPP\mysql\bin\my.ini* for XAMPP):

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G // Change to 50-75% of your system's RAM, depending on how much you need to keep free 
innodb_log_file_size=2G // Change to 25% of the above value
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
```

If you're using another database engine then you'll need to find the equivalent configuration options and tune them accordingly.

Once you've made those config changes, restart your server and run the following in the command-line - although it's using the `mysql` CLI it's just executing plain MySQL,  so you can alternatively copy-paste the SQL part of it directly into a SQL tab into your database tool.

```
mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS <database_name>; USE <database_name>; \ 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0; SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0; \
source <file_name>; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; COMMIT;"
```